# Showing download progress in RecyclerView using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-download-manager

In any row of my `RecyclerView` is a `ProgressBar` and a **download** `Button`. by clicking on this button a download will start. I want to show progress of any download in its `ProgressBar`. anyone can help me?

**Edit:**

my download code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Item item = items.get(position);

    holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                String url = item.getLink();
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setDescription(item.getDescription());
                request.setTitle(item.getTitle());

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(
                        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file"+position+".pdf");

                manager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post some code, what have u tried?

Answer (score 1):

Can't give you any code example right now. But I can give a way.

1. First you need to calculate the progress of the downloaded file by any kind of handler or loop until it is finished
2. In recyclerView adapter you can update partial view item by `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload)` which will call `onBindViewHolder(FeedBaseViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads)`
3. in payload you can pass your desired values perspective with your requirement like start progress action, update progress, stop progress.

Hope it will help you. Thanks in advance.